If SSD begins degrading will that affect online backup?
I have all of my files on an external SSD and am also backing up the entire drive to an online service.
What will happen when my SSD starts degrading eventually? Will that result in corrupted files, so then the backup service will see that the file “changed” and upload the new corrupted copy as well? Then my online backup copies will be corrupt and I’ll lose the original completely?
If it matters, it’s MacOS and the service is Backblaze.

Why exactly do you believe your files will start to become corrupt?

@Ramhound this comment for example “the very design of flash memory makes permanent retention impossible” https://superuser.com/questions/1647730/what-is-the-shelf-life-of-an-ssd#comment2519841_1647879

This seems like a similar question except not about SSDs. So do SSDs not have “bit rot”? https://superuser.com/questions/959431/how-to-fix-bit-rot-back-up-strategy?rq=1

There is no truth in that statement. As an SSD wears it will eventually go into a read-only state, by that very fact, the data won’t become corrupt since it’s physically impossible for the flash cells to be written to again.

@Ramhound I recall reading about data liss after months in the early JEDEC documents - I'm pretty sure they were bit flips. I'm also sure technology has moved in - but I expect  these very,very,very occasionally do happen in modern SSD's

@davidgo - These modern SSD firmware will go into read-only mode. Now if the device fails then I suppose data can become corrupted but you can’t plan for that outside of having multiple backups.

@Ramhound But flash cells can lose their data. Flash cells are nothing else than a tiny capacitor after all, and if those can't be refreshed, they will at some point lose their charge and thus data. I don't think it's guaranteed flash storage fails in the way you describe.

SSD degradation should not normally lead to corrupt files.  Corruption occurs when writing, not reading, so it is easy enough for the firmware to catch this, mark the actual block bad and remap it.
There are a few other things to mention:

A good backup system should version backups.  I've not used Backup Blaze, but it does look like Backup Blaze supports at least some versioning - https://www.backblaze.com/computer-backup/docs/version-history

Bit Rot can hit SSDs - but it can also hit the memory before the content is written to disk [i.e. in memory].   Bitrot is luckily very rare, but if it does happen on disk, the bad copy would not be backed up unless you opened it to edit it, as there is nothing to indicate the bits have flipped (i.e. the creation date and other permissions and meta data relies unchanged).  ZFS periodically scrubs disks - i.e. checks against RAID for bitrot.  If it's any comfort, in the many years I've had a ZFS NAS, it has never reported any bit rot.

You may want to use S.M.A.R.T monitoring/checking to keep an eye on the state of the drive.

You may be technically right by "permanent retention being impossible" - everything eventually dies - however you are generally talking about months to years without powering on - and even then that effect will be gradual.

Generally when an SSD goes, it goes suddenly and catastrophically.



"so it is easy enough for the firmware to catch this" - Completely false; the typical write operation is not verified (i.e. not read back), and is assumed to be successful and correct. You would have to perform a read operation to actually verify the contents using the Error Correction Code, typically a BCH code for SSDs.
